# Replace form.as_p with custom template

Tags: python, html, django, forms

need help to use html templates instead of using the deafult django form.as_p
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47u9N.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yTWM.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBVO9.png)

it tried adding labels with id  and i was exxpecting them to match

Comment: Please include your code directly in your question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to add manually the fields as normal HTML tags but you have to make sure that **each field must have a name attribute that matches the same name in your form or model in case your using ModelForm to create your form**

for example, if your form is like this:

```
class Form():
    some_random_name = forms.CharField()
```

your HTML should be like this:

```
<input name="some_random_name" id=".." class="..">
```